Firestore Composite Index Scope of 'Collection group' extends to regular 'Collection'
I have created two composite indexes of same fields for both the Collection Files and the Collection group Files

Composite Index #1:

category asc
date desc
Scope: Collection



Composite Index #2:

category asc
date desc
Scope: Collection group


They work as expected.
In the case I delete Index #2, I can no longer perform this query on a collection group.
However, when I delete index #1, I can still perform this query on a regular collection.
This means in the presence of both indexes, Index #1 is obsolete. Index #2 works for both Collection and Collection Group.
Is this the expected behavior. If yes, is it recommended or should I keep both for performance, or other reasons.
I have read the documentation, and have not seen this mentioned (explicitly at least).


Is this the expected behavior.

Yes.  You can think of a normal collection query just like a collection group query, except that the results are implicitly filtered on the one specific collection and not all of the collections with the same name.

is it recommended or should I keep both for performance, or other reasons

For your specific case, there is no performance gain by having multiple indexes that effectively do the same thing.  The only cases where multiple indexes have any effect, see the documentation on index merging:

Cloud Firestore can merge the indexes for simple equality filters to build the composite indexes needed for larger equality queries.

Your case doesn't involve using additional fields for simple equality filtering, so there is no advantage to keeping an index that isn't individually necessary.  The unnecessary index just takes up extra space, which incurs costs.
